# Quick questions(trying to see if i understand how to do this)

Tags: java, c

Not looking for someone to write code for, just needing to see if I understand the questions correctly.
1.Write down a program that should work on student data. The data consists of the attributes:-
student name, student id, age, cgpa , height and weight. Please use a structure for this program.
The program should accept the inputs from user. Assume there are 15 students. Please assume
appropriate data types for the attributes. Program should have the following:
a) A structure declaration for the data set above.
b) A function to read the inputs from the user for each student record. [20]
c) A function to display the records.
d) A function to compute the average value of the students age, height weight and the cgpa.

Sorry if its dumb question. I just don't see linked list specified in it so I'm not sure if i'm allowed to use it. But to me it looks like its maybe assumed u can otherwise i'm not sure how i would do it, without like hard coding 15 student structures
This is just asking me to make a linked list of students right?

2. http://prntscr.com/f58mtg
   For this question is it saying i have a linked list of integers and i need to sort it having positive numbers above the negative ones using only stack functions(like push/pop) only?
3. And one last question. how do you get a size of a file in c?

Thanks so much if u can get back to me. this is in C if possible

Comment: One question per post. Is this homework? Show us what you have tried? Please enclose a [MCVE] to demonstrate. Obviously, there is no research effort on your part, into how to actually approach the problem and solve it. Please read the [FAQ] on how to ask a question.

Comment: Ah didn't think I need to do that since I'm not asking for code. I'm just asking if I'm reading the questions right. How is it no effort? lol. I'm just asking if my approach at understanding the problem is correct which i give. I'm not asking someone to just write the program for me

Comment: 1. My initial thought process is its just asking to make a linked list right? Or is there an easier way to do this without linked list.
2.Is this saying its a method that will return a linked list once its sorted? And I need to sort it using stack functions only such as pop/push.
3.I have no clue on this tbh, i don't know why it appeared on my review

Answer (score 1):

I have no Idea why I'm doing your homework for you.

question 1:

```
struct student{char name[50], int age, double cgpa, double height , double weight};
student students[15];

void readStudent(int stuNum){

    printf("enter student name\n");
    scanf(" %s", students[stuNum].name);
    printf("enter age\n");
    scanf(" %d", &students[stuNum].age);
    printf("enter current gpa\n");
    scanf(" %f", &students[stuNum].cgpa);
    printf("enter student height\n");
    scanf(" %f", &students[stuNum].height);
    printf("enter student weight\n");
    scanf(" %f", &students[stuNum].weight);
}

void displayStudent(int stuNum){

    printf("student name %s\n" , sudents[stuNum].name);
    printf("age %d\n" , sudents[stuNum].age);
    printf("current gpa %f\n" , sudents[stuNum].cgpa);
    printf("student height %f\n" , sudents[stuNum].height);
    printf("student weight %f\n" , sudents[stuNum].weight);
}

double getAgeAvg(){

    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++) sum += students[i].age/15.0;
    return sum;
}

double getCgpaAvg(){

    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++) sum += students[i].cgpa/15.0;
    return sum;
}

double getHeightAvg(){

    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++) sum += students[i].height/15.0;
    return sum;
}

double getWeightAvg(){

    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++) sum += students[i].weight/15.0;
    return sum;
}
int main(){ 

    for(int i=0; i<15; i++){

        students[i].age = 0;
        students[i].cgpa = 0;
        students[i].height = 0;
        students[i].weight = 0;
    }
}
```

this should work.

Comment: Ah. I wasn't asking for someone to do my hw. this is just a review :(
I was just wondering if there was another way to do this besides linked list. Thanks though! I forgot I could just use an array and iterate it through like that

Comment: why would you want to use a linked list?

Comment: linked lists in c are really annoying to make.

Comment: yeah you're right. i totally forgot that i could just use an array of structures. i just got done with an assignment where we were forced to used linked list similar to this. idk how it slipped my mind i could just make an array

Answer (score 1):

for question 2 i'll be using java, since I don't know 
how to use Stacks in c.

```
public void posBelowNeg(Stack<Integer> s){

    Stack<Integer> pos = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> neg = new Stack<Integer>();
    while(!s.isEmpty()){
        int current = s.pop();
        if(current >0) pos.push(current);
        else neg.push(current);
    }
    while(!pos.isEmpty()) s.push(pos.pop());
    while(!neg.isEmpty()) s.push(neg.pop());
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

question 3:

I actually googled it , took about two seconds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("somename.txt", "r");
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int sizeOfFile = ftell(fp);
}
```